# Convert given string to palindrome with given substring

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings

Given strings `s1` and `s2`, consider the problem of converting `s1` to a palindrome string `p` such that `s2` is a substring of `p`,
where the only operation allowed on `s1` is replacement of any character with any other character.

What is the minimum number of operations required for this task?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your problem looks like interesting. If it comes from an online course or contest or article, please add a URL _in the question_ using the "edit" link. If it comes from a book or a paper, a reference. Besides paying proper attribute to the original source, that information motivates and helps more people answer your question faster and better.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to answer questions ("How does X work?" "How does Y relate to Z?") that will help you find the right or better approach, but you've just given us a bunch of orders ("Do A!" "Do B and C!"). We are expected to see **a question that comes from you own thoughts**.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I saw this question in an interview test. Cant think of even a brute force approach. **Anything you can think of, please do share.**

Comment: @Apass.Jack I dont have the url, it was a not a publicly available test

Comment: See also: [Convert given string to Palindrome with given substring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54959424) (including an example that confuses me).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of a simple brute force approach that works in $O(n^2)$, where $n$ is the length of $S_1$.

Let $m$ be the length of $S_2$. If $m>n$, return -1 immediately, indicating impossibility.

Keep a counter on how many characters will be changed. Change $S_1$ so that its substring with length m that starts at index 0 is the same as $S_2$. Mark the indexes where characters have been changed. Also chang $S_1$ so that ist substring that starts at index n-1-0 and goes backwards to index n-m-0 is $S_2$ backward. However, abort this try if we have to change the characters that has been marked. Now change the remaining characters of $S_1$ to make it a palindrome. That is, if the character at index $i$ is not same as the character at index $n-1-i$, change the later to be the former. Once done, the counter tells us how many changes is needed to make $S_1$ a palindrome that has $S_2$ as its substring starting at index 0.

Repeat the above with index 0 replaced with index $1, 2, \cdots, n-m$, keeping tracking of the minimal number of changes.

The above description should be enough to set you up. You may want to improve it or look for better algorithms.

Comment: If any of the characters in $S_2$ occurs more than half its frequency in $S_1$, $S_2$ will have to straddle the middle of $S_1$. If additionally $2m < n$, $S_2$ can't be a prefix of the palindrome.